# JavaFX pie Charts ObservableList (Chart GUI update not accurate when passed on Thread)

Tags: multithreading, javafx

please help me guys.. 
my observablelist was updated successfully by background Thread.
but my GUI Update is not accurate.

addPiechart1 to HBOX
addPieChart2 to HBOX

observablelist1= getobservablelist from piechart1

observablelist2= getobservablelist from piechart2

pass observablelist1 to Thread
pass observablelist2 to Thread
ex

on the process i call

animatePie(observablelist1,value1);

animatePie(observablelist2,value2);

```
public void animatePie(ObservableList<PieChart.Data> obs,int[] value){
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
            });
                pieAddToQueue add = new pieAddToQueue(obs,value);
                //add.run();
               executor.execute(add);
    }


private class pieAddToQueue implements Runnable {
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> observableData;
        int[] value;
        int loop;
        public pieAddToQueue(ObservableList<PieChart.Data> obs,int[] value){
            observableData=obs;
            this.value=value;
            loop=0;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

                for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++){
                    observableData.get(i).setPieValue(value[i]);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(MISInfoBoardBottom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your pseudocode, but it looks like you are updating the pie chart (via its data list) from a background thread. You can't do that: you must wrap the calls to `observableData.get(i).setPieValue(...)` in a `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes u got the ideas.  i changed observablelist data in background thread. the observablelist data successfully changed but the piechart in my GUI sometimes don't detect that my observable list was updated by background thread. thats why my piechart sticks few slices. the observable data was updated

Comment: when i add The Platform.runlater as wrapper . the GUI updates after the thread was finished. i hope there was something that updates immediately after changing the data of the observable list in the background thread. :( plss help me.

Comment: You're just wrapping the update to the list, right, not the sleep() call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the UI on a background thread, so you must wrap the calls that change the UI with a `Platform.runLater(...)`:

```
private class pieAddToQueue implements Runnable {
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> observableData;
    int[] value;
    int loop;
    public pieAddToQueue(ObservableList<PieChart.Data> obs,int[] value){
        observableData=obs;
        this.value=value;
        loop=0;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

            for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++){
                PieChart.Data pieChartData = observableData.get(i);
                int v = value[i] ;
                Platform.runLater(() -> 
                    pieChartData.setPieValue(v));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MISInfoBoardBottom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: i got error that says. " local variable feferenced from the lambda expresion must be final  or effectivily final." the observable data cannot be accessed

Comment: See update. (Sorry: I rarely use indexed for loops like that...)